# Android class not found for ACRA.init(this)

Tags: java, android, acra

i am developing one app called nomino. it is already made app and i am trying to run this app for check how it works but when i try to run it i am getting this error in android log-cat. you will find error below.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.acra.ACRA
at com.ten5studios.nomino.Nomino.onCreate(Nomino.java:16)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4344)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: do you have the class file ?

Comment: can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

As I pointed out on Github this means that you have not included the ACRA jar into your APK.

You don't mention what tools you are using to build your Android app. But you need to go back to the documentation for those tools and work out what you have done incorrectly.